# How to apply PIAB in WCF with MEF?

Tags: wcf, mef, policy-injection

I have my service layer serving as a facade over my domain model layer to orchestrate calls to domain objects. I wrote a custome instance provider for my WCF services to harness MEF for instance creation. Now I need to apply PIAB for auditing and logging. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jimmy Tonner has written a nice blog about mixing MEF and PIAB (visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmytr/archive/2010/06/22/mixing-mef-and-piab.aspx). It inspired my solution to applying PIAB to a MEFied WCF service.
Idea is simple: use MEF to manage all your service composition first. Then in the custom instance provider, apply PolicyInjection.Wrap after locating the service instance by MEF container. Below is the code sample:

Service:

```
[Export(typeof(ICustomerService))]
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    #region ICustomerService Members
    public Customer GetCustomer(string customerID)
    {
        return CustomerDAO.GetCustomer(customerID);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Custom instance provider:

```
public class PolicyInjectionInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    private Type serviceContractType;

    private CompositionContainer Container { get; set; } 

    public PolicyInjectionInstanceProvider(Type t)
    {

        if (t!= null && !t.IsInterface)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Specified Type must be an interface");
        }

        this.serviceContractType = t;

    }

    #region IInstanceProvider Members

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message)
    {
        Type type = instanceContext.Host.Description.ServiceType;

        if (serviceContractType != null)
        {
            Compose();
            var importDefinition = new ImportDefinition(i => i.ContractName.Equals(serviceContractType.FullName), serviceContractType.FullName, ImportCardinality.ZeroOrMore, false, false);
            var atomicComposition = new AtomicComposition();
            IEnumerable<Export> extensions;

            Container.TryGetExports(importDefinition, atomicComposition, out extensions);

            if (extensions != null && extensions.Count() > 0)
            {
                var service = extensions.First().Value;
                return PolicyInjection.Wrap(serviceContractType, service);
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            if (!type.IsMarshalByRef)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Type Must inherit MarshalByRefObject if no ServiceInterface is Specified");
            }
            return PolicyInjection.Create(type);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        var disposable = instance as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
        Container.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void Compose()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(@".\")); //Extensions
        Container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    }

    #endregion
}
```